# jquery ui autocompletion selects result items automatically if mouse points on the result list

Tags: jquery-ui, autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

i've got the following code to fetch data from a external source and to display an autocompletion list:

```
function addSearchFieldFunctionality() {

//Clears the value "Search for Products" from the searchfield when clicked and added it back when blured        
$(".searchfield").focus(function(){  
    if($(this).attr("value") != "") $(this).attr("value", "");
}); 


$(".searchfield").autocomplete({
minLength: 1,
source:  "{{ path('SolrSearchBundle_search') }}",
focus: function( event, ui ) {
   $(this).val(ui.item.label);
        return false;
    },
select: function( event, ui ) {
   $(this).val(ui.item.label);
   window.location = "{{ path('CoreBundle_show_product', {'productId': ''}) }}"+"/" + ui.item.value
   return false;
},

open: function(){
    var $searchFieldId = $(this).attr('id');
    //console.log(this);
    $(".ui-autocomplete").append('<li class="ui-menu-item"><span class="notFound"><a class="notFoundItem ' + $searchFieldId + '" href="#">Miss your Product? We\'ll find it</a></span></li>');

}



}).data( "autocomplete" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {

var a = $('<a>', {
    href: "{{ path('CoreBundle_show_product', {'productId': ''}) }}"+"/" + item.value,
    text: item.label,
    "class" : "mySearchClass" 
});

var b = $('<a>', {
    href: "{{ path('CoreBundle_add_product', {'productId': ''}) }}"+"/"+item.value,
    text: "Add", style: "float:right"});
      //return $li.add(a).add(b).appendTo(ul);
return $( "<li></li>" )
.data( "item.autocomplete", item )
.append( a )
.appendTo( ul );
};


}
```

The data i get back from the remote server has the following structure:

```
[{"label":"Try Try Try","value":"816747","thumb":"http:mydomain/myimages/1.jpg"}, ...more results...]
```

I've the following issue: if i'm positioning my mous directly under the search field, lets say always on the fourth position of the result list that's generated, the focus event is always automatically invoked and set the "item.label" to the input search field. For an example i've uploaded a picture.

http://img15.imageshack.us/img15/7619/result1.png

i've typed in the searchterm "try try try", the ul pops down and my mouse focuses directly the fourth result which is "try". The result is, that "try" is now displayed in my search field. if i'm going to enter additionally to the last result "try" a new word and don't move the mouse position (just using the delete button on my keyboard), e.g. "try try", the ul pops down with new results but the mouse focuses automatically the fourth position of the result list, which is again "try". this focused results "overwrites" my searchterm "try try" which was previously there. I can't avoid this behaviour of "autofocussing" on an result item, if i don't move the mousepointer out of the area where the  with the results is generated.

On the example pages of jquery ui : http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#custom-data this works well. if a new  is generated the "focus" on an result item is inactive.

Does anyone know what's going wrong here?
Thank you,
Ramo

EDIT:
Hi, i've now took directly the jQuery example and did a jsfiddle: 
http://jsfiddle.net/zK3Wc/13/
if you place your mousecourse e.g. two cm below the search input field and start typing "s", the selection "Sizzle JS 2" should be preselected. If you now start hitting slowly the back (delete) button, 1 time per second e.g., the value in the search input field is always updated and focused. is this the default behaviour? this only happens, if the mouse resists "in" the resultlist (e.g. two cm below the search input field)

Answer (score 0):

I'm confused, you have specific code in the focus event handler that does exactly what your complaining about.  Try removing:

```
focus: function( event, ui ) {
   $(this).val(ui.item.label);
        return false;
    },
```

Comment: Hi, the problem when removing focus event arises when using my keyboard for navigation, e.g. the down arrow key. pushing the down arrow key allows me to focus on each element. the problem is, that in the search field i didn't get the text of the selected item but the id of the item. so, [{"label":"Try Try Try","value":"816747","thumb":"http:mydomain/myimages/1.jpg"}, ...more results...] would add the id "816747" in the resultlist if i select it via keyboard navigation.

Comment: Even if i remove the focus event, when the result list is reloaded the focus (grey background) disappears in the jquery UI autocomplete example page. the focus is set again, if moving the mouse or interact with the keyboard